# Application Runs ok on .NET 4.0 but not working on .Net 4.6.1

Tags: windows-7

i am facing Error message(Visual C++ **runtime error R6025** pure virtual Function Call) while running my Application on .NET 4.6.1 but application runs OK on .NET 4.0.Actually i want to Run two applications Simultaneously one compatible for 4.6.1 and one to 4.0.